# Generics: Treeset add a Subclass

Tags: java, generics, abstract, superclass, treeset

I'm stuck in the following situation. I got an abstract class called Fusion which should have a TreeSet of so called ClusteringObjects (which is an abstract class as well). Therefore I set the type to

```
 public abstract class Fusion {
   protected TreeSet<? extends ClusteringObject> metadata;
       //CODE
 }
```

In a subclass of Fusion (called TemporalFusion) I want to add TemporalClusteringObjects (subclass of ClusteringObject) to the TreeSet but this doesn't work.

```
  public class TemporalFusion extends Fusion {

    public TemporalFusion(Model metadataModel, String fusionId) {
        //CODE ...
        metadata = new TreeSet<TemporalClusteringObject>(new TimestampComparator());
  }

  public void add(int metadataIndex, ParsedMetadata singleMetadata) {
    //create temporalClusteringObject (works fine)
    metadata.add(temporalClusteringObject);
    }
  }
```

The add gives following failure:

```
  The method add(capture#2-of ? extends ClusteringObject) in the type TreeSet<capture#2-  of ? extends ClusteringObject> is not applicable for the arguments    (TemporalClusteringObject)
```

Is there a generic solution to this problem where not every subclass of Fusion has to implement its own metadata TreeSet with it's own entry type inherit by ClusteringObject?

Comment: Can you make `TreeSet<ClusteringObject>` work in your situation?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: since `ClusteringObject` is an abstract Class this doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The metadata member should use a concrete generic. Either just set it to ClusteringObject or declare a class generic for Fusion.

Example:

`public abstract class Fusion<T extends ClusteringObject> {
    protected TreeSet<T> metadata;`
...

Then declare the derived class like this:

```
public class TemporalFusion extends Fusion<TemporalClusteringObject> {
```

It should work then.